# Range/Step Option on a JQuery XY Pad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a tool that uses the XY-Pad from the JQuery Kontrol Library by Anthony Terrien: [Link](http://anthonyterrien.com/kontrol/).
I need to change the range dynamically for different Parameters. So If I select Parameter1 for X the range and resolution should be adjusted for X. For Example one Parameter goes from 0 to 0.99, another one goes from 65.0 to 297.65, and so on...
Since there is no option to set the step size (default is 1), only min and max, I have not found a way to do this elegantly.
How could I do this nicely without doing weird calculations for each parameter? Or is there maybe a better Library to do this?
My Code Snippet:

```
function xypad(loc,chanx, chany, mini, maxi, scal) {
        $(loc).xy({
            displayPrevious:true,
            min:mini,
            max:maxi,
            fgColor:"#222222",
            bgColor:"#EEEEEE",

            'change' : function (event) {
                    var xyx=(x[0]/50)-0.5*((x[0]-50)/50);
                    var xyy=(x[1]/50)-0.5*((x[1]-50)/50);

                    socket.emit(SLIDER_CHANGED, {channel:chanx, data:xyx/scal});
                    socket.emit(SLIDER_CHANGED, {channel:chany, data:xyy/scal});
            },

            'release' : function (x) { 
                //If Range [-50 <-> +50]
                //To Bring to Scale [0 <-> +1] : (x/50)-0.5*((x-50)/50)
                var xyx=(x[0]/50)-0.5*((x[0]-50)/50);
                var xyy=(x[1]/50)-0.5*((x[1]-50)/50);
                alert('Values changed to '+ 'X: ' + xyx +' Y: ' + xyy);
            }

        })
        .css({'border':'5px solid #0AACCC'})
    }
```

Greetings!
Flitschi

Comment: It looks like the `min` and `max` are for both X and Y...? Maybe yes, find another library. Or just write it yourself.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah you are right. I'll try to find a different library then. Found this one [link](http://www.charlie-roberts.com/interface/) Maybe that'll work. I wouldn't know where to start writing it myself unfortunately.

Comment: Alright, whipped something together: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/L029mtjd/ (I used comments throughout)

Comment: @ChrisG Wow! Thats is so nice of you! It looks really clean. How can I thank you properly?

Comment: You're welcome :) No need to thank me further, but if you like, you can always [buy me a coffee](https://ko-fi.com/khrismuc)

Comment: @ChrisG Hope you enjoy your Coffee ;) Thanks!